# excel VBA macro won't work when triggered by a function

Tags: excel, function, mouseover, vba

I am trying to show a larger version of a graph and some supporting cells when the user hovers the mouse over a sparkline chart.  The idea is to copy an image of the target cells (which includes the graph and supporting cells) and load the image into a user form.

When I call the code from a another macro, everything works well.  However if I trigger it from a function the macro returns a blank screenshot because it can't select the cells to take the picture.  I modified the function so it only updates a cell (CY57) in the spreadsheet and then use the `spreadsheet_change` event to kick off the macro.  In this case the macro runs without an error, but it still does not appropriately select the cells to capture the image and therefore returns a blank image.  If I manually change the target cell (CY57) in the spreadsheet then the `spreadsheet_change` event runs appropriately takes the image.

Here are some more specifics:
I am using the following formula in the cell with the sparkline to call the function:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(Row_Location(ROW()),""),"")
```

Which successfully triggers and runs this function code to update the value in cell CY57:

```
Public Function Row_Location(Data_Row As Integer)
    If ActiveSheet.Range("CY57") <> Data_Row Then ActiveSheet.Range("CY57") = Data_Row
End Function
```

Then I use a `worksheet_change` event to kick off the `ExportRange` macro.  This all works appropriately

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Not Application.Intersect(Range("CY57"), Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then 
       ExportRange
  End If
End Sub
```

The problem occurs in the `ExportRange` macro. I included the code below, but I am not sure you need the whole block.  Without getting into all the tests, I have narrowed down the issue to the fact that it won't allow me to select or active any cells when triggered by a result of a function or directly from the function.  Because I can't do that, it exports a blank image instead of the intended cells.

```
Sub ExportRange() '(rng As Range)
  Dim cob, sc

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Sheets("blank").Range("CX64:Dk85").Select


 Set rng = Selection

 rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture


 Set cob = rng.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, 200, 200)
 'remove any series which may have been auto-added...
 Set sc = cob.Chart.SeriesCollection
 Do While sc.Count > 0
     sc(1).Delete
 Loop



  With cob
    .ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse  '<<< remove chart border
    .Height = rng.Height
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp_image.jpg", Filtername:="jpg"
    .Delete
  End With

UserForm1.Show   

End Sub
```

If I manually type a number into cell CY57 then everything runs fine.  If I call `ExportRange` from another macro it runs fine.

```
Sub Tester()
  ExportRange ' ActiveSheet.Range("CX64:Dk85")
End Sub
```

It is only when the `Worksheet_change` event is triggered by a result of the function that it fail.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you think the issue is from trying to select the cells, have you tried doing `Set rng = Sheets("blank").Range("CX64:Dk85")` instead of the code below?

```
 Sheets("blank").Range("CX64:Dk85").Select
 Set rng = Selection
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately the selection of cells does not work either.  Interesting, I was able to select the chart object and make it work modifying the chart to include a table and some other values.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find a solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by taking another approach.  While VBA did not allow me to select cells, it does allow me to select a chart object.  Therefore, I modified the chart object to show the information I wanted to display by adding some text boxes to the chart object that are formula driven.  I was also able to paste the picture into a comment box instead of a user form.  This created a better experience for the user.

For those wondering, here is the solution I used:

The following formula is in the cell with where the sparkline is shown.  When the mouse is passed over the cell, it calls the function

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(Row_Location(ROW(), ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),""),"")
```

The function captures the row and cell address where the mouse is hovering and save them to the spreadsheet.  The code is saved in a normal module.
Public Function Row_Location(Data_Row As Integer, Mouse_Location As String)
'This captures the row number and address of the cell when the mouse is passed over the cell with this function.  It writes it to spreadsheet to be picked up by another macro.

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("CZ59") <> Data_Row Then

  Application.EnableEvents = False
  'this captures the cell where the mouse is currently hovering
  ActiveSheet.Range("CZ60") = Mouse_Location
  Application.EnableEvents = True

  'this captures the row where the mouse is currently hovering
  ActiveSheet.Range("CZ59") = "=" & Data_Row
End If
```

End Function

Saving the values to the spreadsheet from the function updates a regular graph in the spreadsheet (i.e. a normal chart object, not the sparkline) and triggers the Worksheet_Change which kicks off the macro below.  The code only runs when target cell has been changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Not Application.Intersect(Range("CZ59"), Range(Target.Address)) _
   Is Nothing Then
      'This clears out any previous comments
      Range("F7:N57").ClearComments

      'This captures the image from the chart object
      Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Zoom_Chart").Chart
      Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp_image3.jpg"
      MyChart.Export Filename:=Fname, Filtername:="JPG"

      'This picks up the previously saved location where the mouse is hovering
      Mouse_Location2 = ActiveSheet.Range("CZ60").Value

      'This creates a comment box in the cell where the mouse is hovering and adds the image to the comment box
      Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Mouse_Location2)
      rng.AddComment (" ")
      rng.Comment.Shape.Height = 325
      rng.Comment.Shape.Width = 650

      rng.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp_image3.jpg"
  End If
End Sub
```

The code above takes a picture of the chart object and saves it.  It then adds a comment to the cell where mouse is hovering and imports the picture into the comment box.  When the user moves the mouse off the cell, the comment box automatically hides.  Each time the code is triggered it wipes out the prior comment boxes.